# Get all non-clustered indexes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Does anyone know of a good script to get all the non-clustered indexes for SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For *all* nonclustered indexes in a particular database:

```
select object_name(object_id) as tablename, * 
from sys.indexes where type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED'
```

This will return system and non-system tables. Alternatively:

```
select t.name as tablename, i.* 
from sys.indexes i, sys.tables t
where i.object_id = t.object_id
  and i.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED'
```

for only user-land nonclustered indexes.

Answer (score 4):

You can get all indices for a table using

`exec sp_helpindex 'tablename'`

You can insert this into a table, and delete all rows where the INDEX_DESCRIPTION starts with 'CLUSTERED'

Here is a script for all indices in a database

```
declare @EmptyString varchar(1)
select @EmptyString = ''

-- 35 is the lenght of the name field of the master.dbo.spt_values table
declare @IgnoreDuplicateKeys varchar(35),
    @Unique varchar(35),
    @IgnoreDuplicateRows varchar(35),
    @Clustered varchar(35),
    @Hypotethical varchar(35),
    @Statistics varchar(35),
    @PrimaryKey varchar(35),
    @UniqueKey varchar(35),
    @AutoCreate varchar(35),
    @StatsNoRecompute varchar(35)

select @IgnoreDuplicateKeys = name from master.dbo.spt_values 
    where type = 'I' and number = 1 --ignore duplicate keys
select @Unique = name from master.dbo.spt_values 
    where type = 'I' and number = 2 --unique
select @IgnoreDuplicateRows = name from master.dbo.spt_values 
    where type = 'I' and number = 4 --ignore duplicate rows
select @Clustered = name from master.dbo.spt_values 
    where type = 'I' and number = 16 --clustered
select @Hypotethical = name from master.dbo.spt_values 
    where type = 'I' and number = 32 --hypotethical
select @Statistics = name from master.dbo.spt_values 
    where type = 'I' and number = 64 --statistics
select @PrimaryKey = name from master.dbo.spt_values 
    where type = 'I' and number = 2048 --primary key
select @UniqueKey = name from master.dbo.spt_values 
    where type = 'I' and number = 4096 --unique key
select @AutoCreate = name from master.dbo.spt_values 
    where type = 'I' and number = 8388608 --auto create
select @StatsNoRecompute = name from master.dbo.spt_values 
    where type = 'I' and number = 16777216 --stats no recompute
select o.name,
  i.name,
  'index description' = convert(varchar(210), --bits 16 off, 1, 2, 16777216 on
      case when (i.status & 16)<>0 then @Clustered else 'non'+@Clustered end
      + case when (i.status & 1)<>0 then ', '+@IgnoreDuplicateKeys else @EmptyString end
      + case when (i.status & 2)<>0 then ', '+@Unique else @EmptyString end
      + case when (i.status & 4)<>0 then ', '+@IgnoreDuplicateRows else @EmptyString end
      + case when (i.status & 64)<>0 then ', '+@Statistics else
      case when (i.status & 32)<>0 then ', '+@Hypotethical else @EmptyString end end
      + case when (i.status & 2048)<>0 then ', '+@PrimaryKey else @EmptyString end
      + case when (i.status & 4096)<>0 then ', '+@UniqueKey else @EmptyString end
      + case when (i.status & 8388608)<>0 then ', '+@AutoCreate else @EmptyString end
      + case when (i.status & 16777216)<>0 then ', '+@StatsNoRecompute else @EmptyString end),
  'index column 1' = index_col(o.name,indid, 1),
  'index column 2' = index_col(o.name,indid, 2),
  'index column 3' = index_col(o.name,indid, 3)
from sysindexes i, sysobjects o
where i.id = o.id and
      indid > 0 and indid < 255 --all the clustered (=1), non clusterd (>1 and <251), and text or image (=255) 
      and o.type = 'U' --user table
      --ignore the indexes for the autostat
      and (i.status & 64) = 0 --index with duplicates
      and (i.status & 8388608) = 0 --auto created index
      and (i.status & 16777216)= 0 --stats no recompute
      order by o.name
```

The script is by Giuseppe Dimauro at http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18617

Comment: This didn't deserve a downmod.